# Is it possible to change the firebase username and profile picture?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i have firebase authentication setup but when i use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` it does create the user but what about the User Name/ Display Name? or the profile picture?

Is it possible to change the user name or profile picture in firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're able to change the username, profile picture and more in firebase.

Firebase has an example in the docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

So if you wanted to change the username or profile picture you would have to use the updateProfile method

```
import { getAuth, updateProfile } from "firebase/auth";
const auth = getAuth();
updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
//Replace "Jane Q. User" to the username you desire
//And Replace the PhotoURL with the desired Image
  displayName: "Jane Q. User", photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
}).then(() => {
  // Profile updated!
  // ...
}).catch((error) => {
  // An error occurred
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Is this supported in version 8.2.3? because i am using 8.2.3 for compatibility reasons but is the syntax the same for v8?

Comment: @Dev-Siri Click the link to the documentation to see the v8 code.

Comment: On the docs, you're able to switch between web version 9 to web version 8.